# Proof that only bijective functions have an inverse.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

My professor asked me to proof the statement: "Only bijective functions have an inverse."

I tried to proof this by contradiction:

Let $f: A \to B$ be a function. Assume that this function is not bijective, then one of these 3 cases applies:

1. So it can be injective and not surjective
2. It can be surjective and not injective
3. It can be neither surjective or injective, however we will not regard option 3).

So assume case number 1 is true. Then $Im f \neq B$, this is the same as saying, $\exists b \in B: \nexists a \in A: f(a) = b$. This function would have an inverse, let's name the inverse function $g$, if and only if the following statement is true: $g\circ f= Id_{A}$ and $f\circ g = Id_{B}$. Assume now that $b_1 \in B$ is the element of $B$ which has no image in $A$, then it's impossible that $f\circ g = Id_{B}$ because $f(g(b_1) = \emptyset$.

Now assume case number 2 is true. Then, there exists $x_1,x_2 \in A: f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and $x_1 \neq x_2$. Define $c$ as $f(x_1)$, than we also know that $c = f(x_2)$. Now, let's look at the function $g: B \to A$. We are confronted with the fact that $g(c)$ can either be $x_1$ or $x_2$, so this means that $g$ cannot be the inverse of $f$.

We now can conclude that in order to have an inverse, the function must be surjective and injective, hence bijective. \qed

Comment: Nice work! You can argue directly here, which I think is a bit clearer. Just suppose $f$ has an inverse $g$. Then you can show directly from the definitions that $f$ is injective and surjective. ($y$ is the image of $g(y)$, and if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_1))$).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Ok, thanks for the tip!

Comment: FYI - "proof" is a noun. The verb is "prove".

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks!